# Create a Base class for T generic

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
  builder.Map<Country>();
}
```

And I created the following extension:

```
public static class CountryMapper {
  public static void Map<T>(this ModelBuilder builder) where T : Country {
    builder.Entity<T>().HasKey(x => x.Code);
  }
}
```

This works but I would like to have a generic base class:

```
public class CountryMapper : EntityMapper<Country> {
   // Here override the map extension ?? 
}
```

Basically I would like to apply Map as I am but assuring all Mappers are implemented the same way.

Answer (score 0):

EntityMapper is a class made by you?
and Country can be modified?

I'd add an interface like IEntity that expose a GetKey method like

```
public interface IEntity {
   object GetKey();
}
```

then in country (and every class you need to map), implement that interface, e.g your country could looks like

```
public class Country : IEntity{
   public string Code { get; set; }
   ...
   public object GetKey(){
      return this.Code;
   }
   ...
}
```

then your Map Extension could be generic and based on this interface, like

```
public static void Map<T>(this ModelBuilder builder) where T : IEntity {
   builder.Entity<T>().HasKey(x => x.GetKey());
}
```

note that i wrote it without having a chance to test, but this should point you to the right direction, there is even a little chance this is already working :)

P.S.
if you don't like to have that GetKey method to be easily accessed by anyone (or seen when using visual studio) you can implement it as an explicit interface
should be

```
public class Country : IEntity{
   public string Code { get; set; }
   ...
   object IEntity.GetKey(){
      return this.Code;
   }
   ...
}
```

and then extension, semething like

```
public static void Map<T>(this ModelBuilder builder) where T : IEntity {
   builder.Entity<T>().HasKey(x => ((IEntity)x).GetKey());
}
```